# Hangman game in Python with nine possible words

Tags: python, performance, game, hangman

I'm relatively new to Python, and I've been using the language for about a month. I set out to do the [Hangman game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangman_(game)). I would like to know if there are things to improve in the code of the program I made.

This is the code:

```py
import random

HANGMAN_PICS = ('''
  +---+
  |   |
      |
      |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
      |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
  |   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
=========''')
WORDS = ('Daniel', 'Cristian', 'Lucio', 'Alejandra', 'Delfina', 'Diana', 'Joshua', 'Pedro', 'Rick')
SECRET_WORD = random.choice(WORDS)
found_letters = []
blanks = len(SECRET_WORD) * '_'
print(f'\nSecret word: {blanks}')
print(f'{HANGMAN_PICS[0]}\n')
print('-' * 40)
blanks = list(blanks)
trials = 6

while trials > 0:
    letter = input('\nEnter a letter: ').lower()

    if len(letter) != 1 or not letter.isalpha():
        print('The value entered is invalid.\n')
        print('-' * 40)
    elif letter in found_letters:
        print('This letter has already been entered. Enter another letter.\n')
        print('-' * 40)
    elif letter in SECRET_WORD.lower():
        for i in range(len(SECRET_WORD)):
            if SECRET_WORD.lower()[i] == letter:
                blanks[i] = letter
        found_letters.append(letter)
        print(''.join(blanks))
        print('-' * 40)
    else:
        found_letters.append(letter)
        trials -= 1
        print(f'You missed and lost a life. You have {trials} trials left.')
        print(f'{HANGMAN_PICS[6-trials]}\n')
        print('-' * 40)

    if ''.join(blanks) == SECRET_WORD.lower():
        print(f'You won. The secret word is: {SECRET_WORD}.')
        break
else:
    print(f'You lost. The secret word is: {SECRET_WORD}.')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks pretty good for 1-month coder. Keep it up!

#### Use functions, classes and tests

If you have already learned them - use them. If you haven't - learn them. Start with functions. They are in the language to organize the code. When you have functions, you can test the code.

#### Avoid "magic numbers"

What's 40? What's 6? If you ever want to change horizontal line length to 60 - you should search all the code, and still miss some places where it's not 40 but 39 or something like that, say, if you use '+'+'-'*38+'+' somewhere as a spacer. Instead, introduce a new variable - it can be `SPACER_SIZE = 40` or even `SPACER = '-'*40` - and use it like `print(SPACER)`. This gives you the possibility to change all instances at once and, at the same time, the name to what you're doing and save your time reading the code later.

#### Comparing strings and lists

You have two variables, SECRET_WORD and blanks, to save the secret word and its guessed part. And all over the code you're transforming them this or that way around.
SECRET_WORD is a string with different cases; blanks changes from string to a list of lowercase letters and underscores. I think, the last data type would fit better for both variables; of course, there's a reason to preserve the original SECRET_WORD, so let's introduce a new variable:

```
SECRET_WORD = random.choice(WORDS))
secret_word = list(SECRET_WORD.lower())
blanks = ['-'] * len(secret_word) # this works for lists too
...
elif letter in secret_word: #no call to .lower()
...
    if secret_word[i] == letter:
            blanks[i] = letter
...
if secret_word == blanks: #no join, no lower
```

#### Move identical and related code together

In `if-elif-elif-else` the last line of all branches is `print('-' * 40)`. You can simply move it out of there:

```
if ...: ...
elif ...: ...
elif ... : ...
else: ...
print('-' * 40)
```

The same way you can combine both `found_letters.append(letter)`:

```
if ...: ...
elif ...: ...
else:
    found_letters.append(letter)
    if ...: ...
    else: ...
```

Btw, `set` is usually better than `list` to search for something, so it should be `found_letters = set()` and `found_letters.add(letter)`; but in this case the difference would be so small you'll never notice the difference.

Answer (score 4):

It looks pretty good! The coding style is consistent and it seems to follow the main [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines.

There are some things that I would change though.

## Adding a `main` function

Adding the following pattern avoids polluting the global scope with local names:

```py
def main():
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It allows to define functions containing local variables without risking to overwrite an already existing global variable. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) is a StackOverflow question for more information.

## Adding `r` before the `HANGMAN_PICS` strings

In those strings, the backslash `\` must be displayed verbatim. To make it explicit, it could be wise to add the `r` prefix to each one of them

## Magic numbers

Some constants could be named in the code, or even computed. For example, the number `40` appears multiple times in the `print("-" * 40)` statements. Why not create a function with a default parameter to centralize this value?

```py
def print_sep(length=40):
    print("-" * length)
```

## `trials` management

The `trials` variable is highly coupled with the `HANGMAN_PICS`. It's initial value could even be defined **from** `HANGMAN_PICS`. The total number of trials is also used later in the code, so it could be stored in its own variable:

```py
max_trials = len(HANGMAN_PICS) - 1
trials = max_trials
```

and to avoid the magic number `6`,

```py
print(f'{HANGMAN_PICS[6-trials]}\n')
```

would become:

```py
print(f'{HANGMAN_PICS[max_trials - trials]}\n')
```

## Time complexity

This portion of code has a time complexity of `O(len(secret_word)²)` which does not really matter since `secret_word` is small:

```py
for i in range(len(SECRET_WORD)):
    if SECRET_WORD.lower()[i] == letter:
         blanks[i] = letter
```

But it could be more *pythonic* and efficient to write:

```py
for i, char in enumerate(SECRET_WORD.lower()):
    if char == letter:
        blanks[i] = letter
```

`SECRET_WORD.lower()` is called a lot of times in the code. It's a cheap method call, but I would probably store it in a variable.

## Modified version

Here is the version of the code with the modifications I mentioned:

```py
import random

HANGMAN_PICS = (r'''
  +---+
  |   |
      |
      |
      |
      |
=========''', r'''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
      |
      |
      |
=========''', r'''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
  |   |
      |
      |
=========''', r'''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
=========''', r'''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
      |
      |
=========''', r'''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
      |
=========''', r'''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
=========''')
WORDS = ('Daniel', 'Cristian', 'Lucio', 'Alejandra', 'Delfina', 'Diana', 'Joshua', 'Pedro', 'Rick')


def print_sep(length=40):
    print('-' * length)


def main():
    secret_word = random.choice(WORDS)
    secret_word_low = secret_word.lower()
    found_letters = []
    blanks = len(secret_word) * '_'
    print(f'\nSecret word: {blanks}')
    print(f'{HANGMAN_PICS[0]}\n')
    print_sep()
    blanks = list(blanks)
    max_trials = len(HANGMAN_PICS) - 1
    trials = max_trials

    while trials > 0:
        letter = input('\nEnter a letter: ').lower()

        if len(letter) != 1 or not letter.isalpha():
            print('The value entered is invalid.\n')
            print_sep()
        elif letter in found_letters:
            print('This letter has already been entered. Enter another letter.\n')
            print_sep()
        elif letter in secret_word_low:
            for i, char in enumerate(secret_word_low):
                if char == letter:
                    blanks[i] = letter
            found_letters.append(letter)
            print(''.join(blanks))
            print_sep()
        else:
            found_letters.append(letter)
            trials -= 1
            print(f'You missed and lost a life. You have {trials} trials left.')
            print(f'{HANGMAN_PICS[max_trials - trials]}\n')
            print_sep()

        if ''.join(blanks) == secret_word_low:
            print(f'You won. The secret word is: {secret_word}.')
            break
    else:
        print(f'You lost. The secret word is: {secret_word}.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```